# Como eu tiro informações de dentro de um Array a partir do índice

Tags: javascript, array, índices, slice

Nesse exemplo eu já tenho os números dos *índices* de elementos dentro de um Array, porém eu preciso com esses números tirar a informação de dentro da Array principal.

Essa quantidade de índices é variável, então ele pode mudar a qualquer momento.

```
    IndexNumbers = [ 0, 2 ] // posição das informações na Array
```

Array Principal, da onde eu preciso tirar as informações a partir dos índices:

```
    Array= [ 
        {name: "Teste 3", amount: 15000, day: 17},
        {name: "Teste 1", amount: 80000, day: 10},
        {name: "Teste 1", amount: 800000, day: 17}
    ]
```

Eu tentei usar o método `slice()` já que ele não altera a *Array Principal*, porém não consegui aplicar ele de uma forma que fosse o que eu precisava!

A retorno desejado, teria que ser:

```
    SliceReturn = [ 
      {name: "Teste 3", amount: 15000, day: 17},
      {name: "Teste 1", amount: 800000, day: 17}
    ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode obter isso usando uma combinação de `filter`, para filtrar os elementos do array com `some`, para verificar se index está na lista de index esperados:

```js
var indexes = [ 0, 2 ] // posição das informações na Array

var array= [ 
        {name: "Teste 3", amount: 15000, day: 17},
        {name: "Teste 1", amount: 80000, day: 10},
        {name: "Teste 1", amount: 800000, day: 17}
    ];

// o filter irá filtrar os elementos, baseado no .some, que vai identificar se contem algum ("some") elemento dos indexes esperados
var novoArray = array.filter((e,index) => indexes.some(i => index === i));

console.log(novoArray);
```

Uma outra possibilidade seria usar o `map()`, mapeando a partir de array os itens com o index existente em `indexes`:

```js
var indexes = [ 0, 2 ] // posição das informações na Array

var array= [ 
        {name: "Teste 3", amount: 15000, day: 17},
        {name: "Teste 1", amount: 80000, day: 10},
        {name: "Teste 1", amount: 800000, day: 17}
    ];

var novoArray = indexes.map((item) => array[item])

console.log(novoArray);
```

Documentação do [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) e [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Answer (score 3):

Não precisa de `slice`. Se quer outro array, então... crie outro, e adicione nele os elementos que você quer.

No caso, basta percorrer o array de posições e inserir o respectivo elemento no novo array:

```js
var posicoes = [ 0, 2 ]; // posição das informações na Array
var array = [
    { name: "Teste 3", amount: 15000, day: 17 },
    { name: "Teste 1", amount: 80000, day: 10 },
    { name: "Teste 1", amount: 800000, day: 17 }
];

var result = [];
for (var posicao of posicoes) { // para cada posição
    result.push(array[posicao]); // insere o elemento da posição
}

console.log(result);
```

---

Uma possível melhoria é verificar se a posição de fato existe no array (pois se você acessar uma posição que não existe, será inserido um `undefined` no array final):

```js
var posicoes = [ 0, 2, 7 ]; // atenção, elemento na posição 7 não existe
var array = [
    { name: "Teste 3", amount: 15000, day: 17 },
    { name: "Teste 1", amount: 80000, day: 10 },
    { name: "Teste 1", amount: 800000, day: 17 }
];

var result = [];
for (var posicao of posicoes) {
    if (0 <= posicao && posicao < array.length) // verifica se o array possui a posição
        result.push(array[posicao]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Como o JS não é uma daquelas linguagens que lançam exceção quando se tenta indexar elemento que não existe, acho que daria para simplificar a expressão da condicional: `if (array[posicao]) { ... }`.

Comment: @LuizFelipe No caso do array da pergunta sim, mas em um caso mais geral, e se o array tiver elementos como a string vazia, o número zero, ou até mesmo `null`/`undefined`? Aí daria diferença... :-)

Comment: Nesse caso (provavelmente) nem valeria a pena incluí-los no novo array na maioria das situações, mas, estritamente falando, é verdade.

Comment: @LuizFelipe "*nem valeria a pena incluí-los*" - não tem como saber, cada caso é um caso. Se o único critério é "copiar os elementos destas posições" (independente do valor), é melhor usar o que eu fiz. Se o critério for outro, aí mudamos o `if`, podendo até ser o que vc sugeriu :-)

Comment: Com certeza! Mas estou falando no caso _dessa_ pergunta, até porque se tivesse um  `null`, `undefined` (ou qualquer outro valor que não objeto), o AP teria um _runtime_ error (_cannot access property of undefined_ e similares) em outro lugar da aplicação, a não ser que sempre fizesse a devida verificação antes de usar o array (o que sabemos que não é o caso na maioria das vezes).  De todo jeito, para casos gerais, o que está na resposta realmente é "melhor", foi apenas uma sugestão para este caso. :-)

Comment: essa pergunta foi fechada mas eu sinceramente não achei "fora do escopo"